# How to call python function call subsequently

Tags: python

I have a python function which is working as expected when called first time.
as soon as i add another call it is errors out "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
import os
import re
import glob

LDIR="/data/reports/get-snapshots/labs"
PDIR="/data/reports/get-snapsnots/prod"


def get_latest_snap_files(path, *paths):
    snap_path=os.path.join(path, *paths)
    snap_file=sorted(glob.iglob(snap_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
    return snap_file[0]

def main():
    l=get_latest_snap_files(LDIR, '*')
    print(l)
    p=get_latest_snap_files(PDIR, '*')
    print(p)
main()
```

```
$python h.py
/data/reports/get-snapshots/labs/labs.snapshot.2019-05-25_184501-out.sorted.log

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "h.py", line 22, in main
    p=get_latest_snap_files(PDIR, '*')
  File "h.py", line 16, in get_latest_snap_files
    print(snap_file[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Edit to include the error, please

Comment: I assume that `snap_file` is sometimes an empty list, hence your index error

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup Added.

Answer (score 0):

As per the @Chris_Rands's comment on your answer, `snap_file` is probably empty sometimes.

You should check that and return `None` when that happens.

```
import os
import re
import glob

LDIR="/data/reports/get-snapshots/labs"
PDIR="/data/reports/get-snapsnots/prod"


def get_latest_snap_files(path, *paths):
    snap_path=os.path.join(path, *paths)
    snap_file=sorted(glob.iglob(snap_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
    return None if len(snap_file) == 0 else snap_file[0]

def main():
    l=get_latest_snap_files(LDIR, '*')
    print(l)
    p=get_latest_snap_files(PDIR, '*')
    print(p)
main()
```